# Gulp autoprefixer gives wrong output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, gulp

When I use gulp to autoprefix my stylesheet it is producing the wrong output. Am I doing something wrong in the gulpfile ?

My gulpfile looks like this :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
    sass = require('gulp-sass');
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('wp-content/themes/eovostarter/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('wp-content/themes/eovostarter/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wp-content/themes/eovostarter/'))
  gulp.start('prefix');
});

gulp.task('prefix', function() {
  gulp.src('wp-content/themes/eovostarter/style.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wp-content/themes/eovostarter/'))
  livereload.reload();
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

When I run it on the following scss :

```
.test {
  color:red;
  transform:scale(0.3);
}
```

It produces this in the actual css file :

```
.test {
  color: red;
  transform: scale(0.3); }
0.3);
  transform: scale(0.3); }
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you pipe sass() into autoprefixer ? there is no need for 2 tasks

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `gulp.start` used like that - I don't think that is recommended.  Just make the prefix task dependent on the sass task and call the prefix task in your gulp.watch and it will probably work fine.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('wp-content/themes/eovostarter/sass/**/*.scss', ['prefix']);
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('wp-content/themes/eovostarter/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wp-content/themes/eovostarter/'));
     });

gulp.task('prefix', ['sass'], function() {
  gulp.src('wp-content/themes/eovostarter/style.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wp-content/themes/eovostarter/'))
  .pipe(livereload.reload());
});
```

I don't use livereload but I think you might have to change that call as well to be in a pipe.